# Doctrine - manyToMany on joinColumn

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, yaml

I try to create a manyToMany relation on two of my entities where one id is already use in a internal relation. I put you my code for better comprehension.

```
Entities\Engine\Process:
  type: entity
  table: Engine__Process
  id:
    id:
    type: smallint
  manyToOne:
    initiatorProcess:
      targetEntity: Entities\Engine\Process
      inversedBy: childrenInitiatorProcess
      joinColumn:
        name: initiatorProcessId
        referencedColumnName: id
  manyToMany:
    tags:
      targetEntity: Entities\Engine\Tag
      mappedBy: processes

Entities\Engine\Tag:
  type: entity
  table: Engine__Tag
  id:
    id:
      type: smallint
  manyToMany:
    processes:
      targetEntity: Entities\Engine\Process
      inversedBy: tags
      joinTable:
        name: Engine__ProcessTag
        joinColumns:
          tagId:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          processId:
            referencedColumnName: initiatorProcessId
```

I have tried to switch the manyToMany definition but that not wrok either. I always have the same error message :
     Column name `initiatorProcessId` referenced for relation from Entities\Engine\Tag towards Entities\Engine\Process does not exist.

Anybody have already try something similar ?

Comment: Hi @Naelyth, you haven't declared the column initiatorProcessId in the Process entity have you ? Or when you copying the code here, you just opted out?

Comment: Hi @AnjanaSilva, the column "initiatoriProcessId" is created by the "initiatorProcess" relation. That's my problem, I want my tags linked by the initiatorProcessId and not the classic id.

Comment: Hi @Naelyth, this error clearly says your column 'initiatorProcessId' is does not exist in the Process entity. Try deleting the cache and rebuilding the entity based on yml orm again. (Make sure the missing column is there after building is completed) . Cheers!

Comment: @AnjanaSilva, I already try to drop my database and rebuild and even if I just update the schema the message always come. Clear cache doesn't change anything. The problem is the "initiatorProcessId" variable is create by Doctrine in the oneToMany relation, but I don't know why Doctrine return this error because 'initiatoriProcessId' exists in my Entity, even if the error come. This is just in the database that block.